# Google Translate API and word correction

Tags: api, google-translate

translate.google.com corrects word and shows some additional info about it

[image: translate.google.com example]

But Google Translate API returns only translation:

[image: wrong translation]

Also, it doesn't translating incorrect words.

**Q.** Can I somehow translate incorrect words with API?

Comment: Even if you had access to Google's autocorrect API, which autocorrection would you choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no mechanism to do this built into the Google Translate API as of right now.

You'd need to do this correction on your end prior to requesting a translation.